# Environment variable in jenkins not printing

Tags: powershell, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am creating an environment variable in my freestyle Jenkins project like this

```
$files1 =Get-ChildItem $ENV:WORKSPACE/altab
write-output $ENV:WORKSPACE
$linklist = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
$prefix="http://x.x.x.x:8080/job/ws/altab/"
foreach ($file in $files1) {
  $url1 = '<a href='+'"'+[uri]::EscapeUriString($prefix+$file.Name)+'">'+'PDF LINK'+'</a>'
  $null = $linklist.Add($url1) 
 }
$links = $linklist | Out-String
"LINKS_VAR=$links" | Out-File env.properties -Encoding ASCII
```

The environment variable looks like this

```
LINKS_VAR=<a href="http://x.x.x.x:8080/job/ws/altab/EC2AMAZ-MTI08HS_Open%20Google_20220504-064713.pdf">PDF LINK</a>
<a href="http://x.x.x.x:8080/job/ws/altab/EC2AMAZ-MTI08HS_Open%20Google_20220504-065759.pdf">PDF LINK</a>
<a href="http://x.x.x.x:8080/job/ws/altab/EC2AMAZ-MTI08HS_Open%20Google_20220504-070700.pdf">PDF LINK</a>
```

I am using the email extension plugin in Jenkins to send this environment variable in the email. In the email body I have `LINKS_VAR`. However, only first URL is being sent in the mail. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this. Add a `<br>` tag instead of a new line like you are doing.

```
$files1 =Get-ChildItem $ENV:WORKSPACE/altab
write-output $ENV:WORKSPACE
$linklist = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
$prefix="http://x.x.x.x:8080/job/ws/altab/"
foreach ($file in $files1) {
  $url1 = '<a href='+'"'+[uri]::EscapeUriString($prefix+$file.Name)+'">'+'PDF LINK'+'</a>'+'<br>'
  $null = $linklist.Add($url1) 
 }

"LINKS_VAR=$linklist" | Out-File env.properties -Encoding ASCII
```